# How to replace 2nd iteration in a string - Python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to remove a word from a string but only if it is the second word. Here is an example:

I have tried strip and replace. Slicing wont work because Preds might not be in the same place everytime.

```
# Complete the function to remove the word PREDS from the given string
# ONLY if it's not the first word and return the new string
def removePREDS(mystring):
    return mystring.replace("PREDS", ' ')

# expected output: PREDS Rocks
print(removePREDS('PREDS Rocks'))

# expected output: Hello, John
print(removePREDS('Hello, PREDSFan'))
```

I can remove both Preds and the first one but cant figure out how to remove on the second one

Comment: Only second or replace all repeats except first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Function:**

```
def remove_if_not_starts_from(src, substr):
    return src if src.startswith(substr) else src.replace(substr, '')
```

**Usage:**

```
str1 = 'Lorem ipsum'
str2 = 'ipsum Loremipsum'
word = 'Lorem'

print('{} -> {}'.format(str1, remove_if_not_starts_from(str1, word)))
print('{} -> {}'.format(str2, remove_if_not_starts_from(str2, word)))
```

**Output:**

```
Lorem ipsum -> Lorem ipsum
ipsum Loremipsum -> ipsum ipsum
```

Comment: Thats it, I did not think about the startswith idea. Thank you very much